# Android overflow button overlay / always visible

Tags: android, button, overlay, visible

I'm trying to get a button to be always on top (just when the application is active, not like the facebook messenger one).

How do I accomplish that?

Since i have a main activity, which switches out the fragments, I can't create the button in the fragments, and it seems that I can't initialise a button in the main activity that will be on top of those fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the `button` and other views of `activity_main.xml` inside a `FrameLayout`. Put everything else except the `button` inside a `RelativeLayout`(or whatever you want) and then put the `button` as the last element of the parent `FrameLayout`.

Now set the content area for `fragment` somewhere inside that `RelativeLayout` so that your fragment will be replaced in that area only. By doing this the `button` will be displayed on top of your fragments too. Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you very much for the help, I will try to implement it, and will post a "status comment" when I'm done.